# Displaying all microposts in a select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code creates a select box

```
<%= select_tag "microposts", options_from_collection_for_select(@microposts, "id", "name"), { :prompt => 'All microposts' } %>
```

I want to show all the microposts in a select box, but i get the following error

```
NoMethodError in Managments#edit
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap
```

Can someone explain to me how to display all the microposts in a select box?

controller

```
class ManagmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

    def index
     @managments = current_user.managments
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    end

  def show
     @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @managment = Managment.find_by(id: params[:id])
   if !@managment
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
   end
   @user = @managment.user

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @managment = Managment.new
  end

  def edit
     @managment = Managment.find(params[:id])
  end

    def create

     @managment = current_user.managments.build(managment_params)
     if @managment.save
      flash[:success] = "Managment created!"
      redirect_to @managment
     else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'new'
     end
    end

  def update
     @managment = Managment.find(params[:id])

    if @managment.update(managment_params)
      redirect_to @managment
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @managment.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Managment deleted"
    redirect_to managments_path
  end


  private

    def managment_params
      params.require(:managment).permit( 
      :title,  :budget,
      :procent1, :procent2, :procent3, :procent4,
      :procent5, :procent6, :procent7,
      :procent8, :procent9, :procent10,
      :procent11, :procent12, :result1,
      :result2, :result3, :objectivesname1,
      :objectivesname2, :objectivesname3, 
      :lowprocent1, :lowprocent2, :lowprocent3,
      :medprocent1, :medprocent2, :medprocent3,
      :highprocent1, :highprocent2, :highprocent3,
      :lowobjectives1, :lowobjectives2, :lowobjectives3,
      :medobjectives1, :medobjectives2, :medobjectives3,
      :highobjectives1, :highobjectives2, :highobjectives3

      )
    end

    def correct_user
      @managment = current_user.managments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to managments_path if @managment.nil?
    end

end
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: @Iceman I changed it

Comment: Seems that `@microposts` is `nil`, are you not instantiating it in the controller?

Comment: @Iceman I've added my controller it is in there

Comment: Not in the `edit` action, the error says it's missing there `NoMethodError in Managments#edit`

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to pull it of thanks to you. Thank you, I've got one more question though. How do save the selected micropost with the form?

Comment: You should start another question for that if you don't figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: @Iceman Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to the question can be find in the comments

```
def edit
  @managment = Managment.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```